# How to connect and copy file to Windows 8 system from Ubuntu 12.04 via network using command line?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ssh, scp

We have separate `Ubuntu` client systems and `Windows` system connected via LAN. My requirement is to copy a file to `Windows 8` system via command line using utility like `scp`. For that we have to run `ssh-server` in Windows. I have tried that by installing `Cygwin` in `Windows` but when tried to connect using `ssh` from `Ubuntu`, the message is `Connection timed out`.

But I am able to ping the `windows` system by disabling the `Firewall`. How to make the Windows run `ssh-server` daemon?

Is there any other means to copy a file to `Windows` from `Linux` system. `scp` is preferred because we can copy user `rsa key` to `authorized_keys` of windows user so that each time password entry can be avoided.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "How to make the Windows run ssh-server daemon?" How would we know? We support Ubuntu. Windows related questions need to be asked on http://superuser.com/ "Is there any other means to copy a file to Windows from Linux system." is also a question regarding Windows.

Comment: I have to get doc files converted to another format to use it as input for a bash script in `Ubuntu` machine. Even `libreoffice` is available in Ubuntu it has  problem with `math` part and with text alignment.

Answer (score 1):

For windows I can propose [freesshd](http://www.freesshd.com/).
After installing you can transfer file using command

```
scp root@ip_address_of_server:/path/to/file.txt localfile.txt
```

Comment: I have successfully installed  `freesshd` and could successfully `ssh` in Windows, but in windows `cmd`  prompt. Whether by any means possible to get bash? `Cygwin` is installed in `Windows`, also `ssh-server` package.